# Use graphical methods to solve the linear programming problem. Maximize:

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

Use graphical methods to solve the linear programming problem.

Maximize: $z= 4x+2y$

subject to : $x-y\le 7$

$19x+12y\le 228$

$18x+18y \le 324$

$x\ge 0,y\ge 0$

the max is ??  when x= ?? and y=???

my effort

$x-y\le 7$

when $x= 0 , y=0$,we get,$(0, -7)  ,(7, 0)$

$19x+12y\le 228$

when $x= 0 , y=0$,we get $(12, 0)  ,(0, 19)$

$18x+18y \le 324$

when$ x= 0 , y=0$, we get, $ (18, 0),(0, 18)$

We evaluate the objective function to maximize
at each corner point:

$z= 4x+2y$

$(0,0)\Rightarrow 0$

$(7, 0)\Rightarrow 28$

$(12, 0)\Rightarrow 48$

$(18, 0)\Rightarrow 72$

The maximum value of $z$ is $72$, and will occur at $(18,0)$, when $x=18$ and $y=0$

Please review my answer.

Comment: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: You forgot the constraint $x-y \leq 7$, which is not satisfied by your solution.  Perhaps you took the wrong side of the constraint?

Comment: how that ???????

Comment: Pretty straightforward, isn't it?  $x-y = 18-0 = 18 > 7$.

Comment: You should draw out the constraint set and examine which points are actually in it.

Comment: yes, I know that I should draw but I didn't know which program can draw this constraints

Comment: @zorbha This software is very good for this purpose: https://www.padowan.dk/download/

Comment: @zorbha Could you handle the exercise ? Or are you still interested in an answer ?

Answer (score 1):

Try plotting the region using [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=RegionPlot%5Bx%20%3C%3D%207%20%2B%20y%20%26%26%2019%20x%20%2B%2012%20y%20%3C%3D%20228%20%26%26%20x%20%2B%20y%20%3C%3D%2018%2C%20%7Bx%2C%20-10%2C%2010%7D%2C%20%7By%2C%20-20%2C%2030%7D%5D)

(The code looks like this: `RegionPlot[x <= 7 + y && 19 x + 12 y <= 228 && x + y <= 18, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -20, 30}]`)

It has 4 vertices, figure out where is the extreme value of the objective function you are looking for...